# net core and video transcoding on aws lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ffmpeg

I'm looking for a solution to:

1. upload video to s3 bucket
2. after video upload an aws lambda function will be triggered
3. lambda function will use ffmpeg layer in order to transcode video (mainly cropping with other functionalities)
4. save result (transcoded video into s3 bucket)

My language of choice inside lambda is c# and net core runtime.

I have found various resources for video manipulation with aws ffmpeg layer using lambda function but no examples in net core lambda.

My question is:

> Can I use existing *FFmpeg/FFprobe Lambda Layer for Amazon Linux* such
> as [this one](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/145266761615/ffmpeg-lambda-layer) with lambda function written in c# and .net core?

Another question:

> Would you suggest Amazon Elastic Transcoder as a better choice with
> lambda function .net core integration?

Comment: I don't think Lambda is really a suitable place for transcoding. Yes, you can use ffmpeg and ffprobe in Lambda functions, but I don't think the long-running nature of transcode jobs fits well with Lambda. As far as I'm aware the limit is 15 minutes, isn't it?

Comment: Any chance you work with ffmpeg inside .net core lambda? I guess you are suggesting elastic transcoder instead?

Comment: I used to use ffmpeg inside Lambda for extracting thumbnails, but we moved that to Google Cloud Functions. For video transcodes we used to use ZenCoder (Brightcove) but that got rather expensive so we ended up building our own transcoding service on Google Kubernentes Engine, using preemptible nodes to help bring down the cost down (and accepting that sometimes Google would reclaim those nodes in the middle of a transcode).

Comment: For that thumbnails creation, you used c# inside lambda (cause I've found only nodejs examples online)? If so can you point me in right direction (ffmpeg inside lambda with c#).

Comment: If I remember correctly, I just took [John Van Sickle's static builds](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and packaged them with my .zip code file. The one issue I did have was that because I was building and publishing on Windows, the zip file didn't have the permissions included with it, so the files weren't executable. I ended up creating a [Python script](https://pastebin.com/ntW45MHD) that I ran locally before uploading the ZIP to AWS. This went through the file and applied permissions to all of the files inside, which allowed me to execute ffmpeg.

Comment: As to how I worked with ffmpeg, I've always launched it directly via `Process` rather than using any third party NuGet packages. In my case, our API would send signed URLs for retrieving the video and PUTting the resultant image, so I didn't need any other functionality re S3, etc. Note: my experience with doing this on Lambda is a few years out of date now, so I don't know how relevant all of this still is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can transcode files using ffmpeg layer inside lambda. I have a code written in python which transcodes a file uploaded to s3 bucket into H.264(another bucket). Python and little bit of C++ are the only languages i know(newbie). So, i can't help with C#. If you are interested, i could share the logic or post my python code. I believe transcoding with lambda is better than AWS Media Transcoder considering the different options provided by ffmpeg  , free 400000 gb/s and lambda being less costly (based on my calculations).